# what is the difference between "withRun" and "inside" in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I am trying to execute `npm run test` inside a container. 
When I run with `inside` it fails but when I run with `withRun` it runs as I want to.

Code for reference
with `inside`

```
stage('Test') {
    docker.image('justinribeiro/chrome-headless').inside ("-p 9222:9222 --security-opt seccomp=$WORKSPACE/chrome.json") { 
        sh label: 
        'Running npm test', 
        script: '''
        npm run test
        '''
      }
    }
```

With `withRun`

```
stage('Test') {
    docker.image('justinribeiro/chrome-headless').withRun ("-p 9222:9222 --security-opt seccomp=$WORKSPACE/chrome.json") { 
        sh label: 
        'Running npm test', 
        script: '''
        npm run test
        '''

    }
  }
```

Now I want to understand what is the difference between them.

I have observed that `inside` adds volumes and runs `cat` on container whereas `withRun` does not.

I also read the documentation https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ but did not understand well enough.

A much more detailed explanation will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

> Image.run([args, command])
> Uses `docker run` to run the image, and returns a Container which you could stop later. Additional args may be added, such as '-p 8080:8080 --memory-swap=-1'. Optional command is equivalent to Docker command specified after the image. Records a run fingerprint in the build.

> Image.withRun[(args[, command])] {…}
> Like `run` but stops the container as soon as its body exits, so you do not need a `try-finally` block.

> Image.inside[(args)] {…}
> Like `withRun` this starts a container for the duration of the body, but all external commands (sh) launched by the body run inside the container rather than on the host. These commands run in the same working directory (normally a Jenkins agent workspace), which means that the Docker server must be on localhost.

So as you can tell from the above, your `sh` method commands (specifically the `npm` commands) will execute on the host for `withRun`, but within the container for `inside`.

The documentation source is automatically loaded into the Jenkins UI for viewing (in the global variables section) when the Docker plugin is installed, but Cloudbees also provides a [screenshot of the documentation](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/_images/docker-workflow-screenshots/dsl-help.dbaf851.png) online.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It really explains the difference well. But I have a question. I did not see anywhere `image.run` has this been deprecated? @matt-schuchard

Comment: @Ismail You can still invoke the `run` method like you are invoking `withRun` and `inside` and it will have the effects described above.

Comment: tried with both 
`docker.image('<image_name>').inside(' --security-opt seccomp=$WORKSPACE/chrome.json')` 
and 
`docker.image('<image_name>').run()` 
but got same error: 
`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.run() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@53fed3]
Possible solutions: find(), dump(), any(), grep(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), print(java.io.PrintWriter)`

Comment: Could you state where this doc snippet is from? It would allow further reading :)

Comment: @Matt Schuchard Yes, could you please give your reference? I will then happily +1 ;)

Comment: Here it comes @Worp and tharibo: https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals (I'd be happy to edit but "suggested edit queue is full" :(

Comment: @EnzoMolion Amazing! I took the liberty to suggest the edit on your behalf. Thank you!

Comment: Link to docs is broken

Comment: @IvanRubinson Someone edited my answer with a third party link. I have edited the answer myself with proper documentation source information.