# Run multiple updated Docker containers in Jenkins pipeline separated steps without inside commands

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to run 2 docker containers in Jenkins pipeline separated steps. 
I am looking for the exact code to do so in a pipeline. 
The issue is that I found an example with running command/s inside the Docker container. 
I don't need to run any other command rather than the container's default. 
Also, the containers should both run in the same specific Docker network. 
I don't want to use a Dockerfile to run each container. 
The container images are downloaded from DockerHub. 
I'm trying to avoid shell commands in the Jenkins pipeline  (sh) like:

```
sh 'docker pull someimage:latest'
```

Edit: 
Currently I cannot run a container and leave it running because

> docker.image('someimage').run

doesn't work. 
I get an error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
> signature of method:
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.run() is applicable for
> argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [server] Possible
> solutions: dump(), find(), grep(), any(), build(java.lang.String),
> find(groovy.lang.Closure)

The only options which work are .withRun or .inside but the container stops after a few seconds.

[The jenkinsfile without the exact URLs and Docker image name](https://pastebin.com/xww3ppv2)

[docker.image .withRun and .inside examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57478006/3341782)

Comment: This seems like you have a couple of specific questions, one around the mechanics of starting the containers and one around using the most recent build.  Can you split this question into two, making sure to include relevant parts of yourJenkinsfile in each?

Comment: I changed the question to be more specific

Comment: The second question about Docker image cache in the Jenkins pipeline(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639155/run-docker-containers-in-jenkins-pipeline-and-pulling-latest-image-only-when-nec)